# Author list 'special' author first then 'normal' author

Tags: author, user-meta, order

Currently I'm trying to create a author list with all authors but on top some 'special' authors. The 'special' authors should result first and shouldn't be available in the list with normal authors.

The 'special' authors have in usermeta a meta key called 'werksortgodmodus' with meta value 'yes'. The 'rest' of the authors have 'werksortgodmodus' = no .

The result should be something like this:

[author with godmodus], [author with godmodus], [author with godmodus], [normal author], [normal author], [normal author].

This is the code I found and stripped to get authors. How can I get authors with godmodus on top?

**[edit]** replaced code with original code **[/edit]**

```
    <?php
    $display_admins = false;
    $order_by = 'display_name'; 
    $role = 'author';
    $avatar_size = 64;

if(!empty($display_admins)) {
    $blogusers = get_users('orderby='.$order_by.'&role='.$role);
} else {
    $admins = get_users('role=administrator');
    $exclude = array();
    foreach($admins as $ad) {
        $exclude[] = $ad->ID;
    }
    $exclude = implode(',', $exclude);
    $blogusers = get_users('exclude='.$exclude.'&orderby='.$order_by.'&role='.$role);
}
$authors = array();
foreach ($blogusers as $bloguser) {
    $user = get_userdata($bloguser->ID);
    if(!empty($hide_empty)) {
        $numposts = count_user_posts($user->ID);
        if($numposts < 1) continue;
    }
    $authors[] = (array) $user;
}        
    echo '<ul class="contributors">';
    foreach($authors as $author) {
        $display_name = $author['display_name'];
        $description = get_userdata($author['ID'])->user_description;
        $avatar = get_avatar($author['ID'], $avatar_size);
        $author_profile_url = get_author_posts_url($author['ID']);

        echo '<li><h3>'.$display_name.'</h3><a href="', $author_profile_url, '">', $avatar , '</a><p>'.$description.'</p><p><a href="', $author_profile_url, '" class="contributor-link">➤ Posts by '.$display_name.'</a></p></li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
    ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The 'special' authors have in usermeta a meta key called
>   'werksortgodmodus' with meta value 'yes'. The 'rest' of the authors
>   have 'werksortgodmodus' = no .

You could e.g. order by the meta value with (*PHP versions 5.4+*):

```
$blogusers = get_users( 
    [ 
        'role'     => 'author',
        'meta_key' => 'werksortgodmodus', 
        'orderby' => [ 'meta_value' => 'DESC', 'display_name' => 'ASC' ], 
    ] 
);
```

where we order first by the `werksortgodmodus` meta value and then by e.g. `display_name`.

We use the `DESC` order so that the `yes` values come before the `no` values.

If you got huge number of users, then you might want to use query pagination.

Comment: `As of PHP 5.4 you can also use the short array syntax, which replaces array() with [].` - not everyone has got PHP 5.4+ so you should change `[]` to `array()` ([source](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.array-func))

Comment: Thanks for notice, I usually add the notice to my snippets, when I remember. But this is also to promote visitors to avoid the old PHP versions. I stick to the short array notation ;-) @KrzysztofGrabania

Comment: This looks what I'm looking for, but how do I embed it to my current code? Sorry I'm still basic PHP..

Comment: How do you fetch data into `$blogusers`? Please add that to the question. @rwzdoorn

Comment: Added the missing code from original code!

Comment: ok, it looks like you're using `get_users()`. I updated my answer, so now you should try to adjust it to your needs. There's also the `role__in` and  `role__not_in` attributes avialable. If you have a large number of users then you might need a different approach to increase performance. @rwzdoorn